# Can I omit this catch block for this promise arrangement?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

I'm trying to use best practice.  And per my understanding you only need a catch clause at the end of a promise chain.

However this is not a straight forward chain. `createUser()` is in a then method.  However should not any errors in `createUser()` be caught in `getOrCreateUser()`?

Can I omit the catch clause in `createUser()`?

```
function getOrCreateUser (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  const user_props = obtainUserPropsFromGoogle(profile);
  DBM.getUser(user_props.id_google).then( (res) => {
    return res[0] ? done(null, user_props) : createUser(done, user_props);
  }).catch( error => {
    return done(error, null);
  });
}

function createUser (done, user_props) {
  DBM.createUser(user_props).then(() => {
    return done(null, user_props);
  }).catch( error => {
    return done(error, null);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I omit the catch clause in `createUser()`?

No, not the way the code is written.

In order to remove the `catch` from the *inner* promise, the *outer* promise needs to handle the rejection of the inner promise.

For that to happen, you need to return the inner promise from `createUser`. Then, you need to return that promise from the `then` handler on the outer promise.

You effectively have this:

```
Promise.resolve.then(() => {
  Promise.reject()
}).catch(/* cannot handle Promise.reject above */)
```

What you *need* is this:

```
Promise.resolve.then(() => {
  return Promise.reject();
}).catch(/* correctly handles above Promise.reject */)
```

In practical terms, your code should look like this:

```
function getOrCreateUser (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  const user_props = obtainUserPropsFromGoogle(profile);
  DBM.getUser(user_props.id_google).then( (res) => {
    // Now that `createUser` returns its promise, this `return` is actually useful
    return res[0] ? done(null, user_props) : createUser(done, user_props);
  }).catch( error => {
    done(error, null);
  });
}

function createUser (done, user_props) {
  // This promise must be returned out of `createUser`
  return DBM.createUser(user_props).then(() => {
    done(null, user_props);
  })
}
```

Comment: So ... should I refactor my code or leave it as is?